# Use AJAX with aspx backend?

Tags: ajax, vb.net

Very new to AJAX, but have learned a bit from online tutorials.  If I was using PHP all would be well, but...

...I have to use VB.Net. Microsoft provides black magic tools (in the Visual Studio IDE) for making AJAX work, but using these seems hopelessly complicated and documentation for these tools covers only the simplest examples.  By contrast, writing the scripts myself seems much easier, and I will understand what is going on.

So my question is, is it possible to write my own AJAX javascript (creating the XMLHttpRequest object, etc.), and have the server-side function be written in VB.Net instead of PHP?  Has anyone ever tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.  You can implement an HttpHandler on the server to give you full control of what happens with the request and the response.  The Microsoft AJAX thing is kind of like a black magic box, but ASP.NET is not.

Here is a starting point:

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    #region IHttpHandler Members

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write("Hello AJAX World");
    }
}
```

And don't forget to register the handler in the web.config ;)

```
<add name="ajax_page.ashx*" 
     path="ajax_page.ashx" 
     verb="*" 
     type="MyNamespace.MyHandler, MyAssembly" />
```

Here is my best guess at what this should look like in VB.NET (NOTE: I have never written a single line of VB.NET)

```
Public class MyHandler 
    Inherits IHttpHandler

    Public Property IsReusable() As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context as HttpContext)
        context.Response.Write("Hello AJAX World")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you! But how do I get to this from the client? The tutorial code I've found has "ajaxRequest.open("GET", "nameOfServerSideFile", true)", but this seems not to work with just a file name. Don't I have to specify the "ProcessRequest" method somewhere?

Comment: @Noel Taylor, You can use the same code you used to do AJAX with PHP.  BTW, are you not using jQuery or some other javascript library?  It makes doing AJAX way easier!

Comment: I'm not using jQuery, etc, b/c it will obscure the under-the-hood details from me. When I learn AJAX better, I'll probably use it, but for now I like seeing the baseline code.
However, I'm not having any luck getting the server-side code to respond.  In PHP I can "echo" the response, but VB.Net doesn't have something like that does it?  And since I can't call a specific method within the class I don't know how to send back the response in a return value.  Can you illuminate?  Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: Btw, when I try to use the code above, Visual Studio won't accept the syntax "MyClass : IHttpHandler".  It underlines "IHttpHander" as an error and gives me the not-too-helpful message "Declaration Expected"

Comment: @Noel Taylor, I put in my best guess at VB.NET.   Also, context.Response.Write() is pretty much the exact same as echo()

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, I've been hacking away myself.  In VB.Net (at least) IHttpHandler is an interface, not a class, so I used "Implements" instead of "Inherits".  `Partial Public Class Transaction
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
  Implements IHttpHandler` The methods I wrote like this: `  Public Shadows ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean
    Get
      Return True
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Shadows Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext)
    context.Response.Write("Hello")
  End Sub`

Comment: Oh, I thought backticks would yield code blocks like the ones you posted above, but I guess that doesn't work

Comment: The javascript looks like this `        function AjaxFunction() {
          var ajaxRequest;
          if (document.all) {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          }
          else {
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
          ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
              document.getElementById("foo").appendChild(document.createTextNode("'" + ajaxRequest.responseText + "'"));
            }
          }

Comment: ajaxRequest.open("GET", "Transaction.aspx.vb", true);
          ajaxRequest.send(null);
        }

Comment: Sorry, had to break up all that code into two comments due to length restrictions. Anyway, it almost works: I actually get some text out the other end, but it doesn't say "hello". It has a really long error message that it can't find the specified file (i.e. "Transaction.aspx.vb") even though it is definitely spelled right, etc.

Comment: I think you can only specify .aspx files, but not .aspx.vb files (the "codebehind" file), and so I don't know how you're supposed to do any real coding, since .aspx files are just for static elements and javascript. You can't have looping / branches / etc. of the kind I need in order to output the data I want

Comment: You've already helped a lot. Thank you very much. You can sense the frustrtaion, I'm sure.

Comment: @Noel Taylor, I'm a little confused by what you have done.   I didn't say anything about making an aspx file (that's a page).  You need to register the handler in the web.config file and then whatever you register as (ajax_page.ashx in my example) is what you want to call from the javascript.  I highly recommend getting the handler working first (you can simply access the URL from a web browser) and then trying to get the AJAX to work.

Comment: @Noel Taylor, frustration will occur whenever you are new to technologies and don't use things as they are designed to be used.  WebForms are designed to use update panels for ajax (note: I never use update panels).  Javascript may as well be designed to use a framework like jQuery.  Just take a look here to see how easy it could be and how hard you are making it on yourself:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: OK, been fooling with this more today, and have made it work, although the way I'm doing it is very convoluted... I had hoped to make the .aspx file into a handler by making it implement IHttpHandler, but that only kind of worked.  So I made a separate handler with extension .ashx like you suggested.  That worked better, but now I've got 1) a .aspx file that contains the javascript that creates the XHttpRequest object, 2) a .aspx.vb codebehind that populates the placeholders in the .aspx file dynamically and that sets the "onclick" value for each interactive element to call said function...

Comment: and 3) a .ashx handler to do the AJAX stuff. Can this be right? It seems too jury-rigged to me, but who knows? It works, I guess, although now I'm looking at transferring *loads* of code that used to be in the .aspx.vb codebehind into the .ashx handler because the data output to the user is based on what the user clicked, and to get that data the code has to hit a remote web-service and display the output in a data grid. But is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: @Noel Taylor, everything sounds right to me.  Although, I don't know why IHttpHandler "kind of" worked for you.